# Segmentation fault in merge sort program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mergesort

I made the following c program for mergesor. Then I executed it using gcc compier on my system and it gave a segmentation fault. I am unable to figure out what in the program is causing this error. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void mergersort(int A[], int, int);
void merge(int A[], int, int, int);

void merge(int A[], int middle, int p, int q) {
    int buffer1[30], buffer2[30], i, j, k, n1, n2;
    n1 = middle-p+1;
    n2 = q-middle;
    for (i = p; i <= middle; i++) {
        buffer1[i-p] = A[i];
    }
    for (j = middle+1; j <= q; j++) {
        buffer2[j-i] = A[j];
    }
    i = 0; j = middle; k = 0;
    while (i!=n1 || j!=n2) {
        if (buffer1[i] <= buffer2[j]) A[k++] = buffer1[i++];
        else A[k++] = buffer2[j++];
    }
    while (i != n1) {
        A[k++] = buffer1[i++];
    }
    while (j != n2) {
        A[k++] = buffer2[j++];
    }
}

void mergesort(int A[], int p, int q) {
    if (p < q) {
       int middle = (p+q)/2;
       mergesort(A,p,middle);
       mergesort(A,middle+1,q);
       merge(A,middle,p,q);
    }
}

int main() {
    int A[] = {56,23,33,1}, i;
    mergesort(A,0,3);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%d", A[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Update: I solved the problem.I should have paid more more attention. Apart from the segmentation fault which was solved after I changed || to &&, the output was not correct. Instead of k=0 in merge procedure, it should be k=p.

Comment: Segmentation fault -> debug!!

Comment: How many elements did you give for the input?

Comment: @GoodDeeds `{56,23,33,1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside merge() the assignment of i,j,k

```
i = 0; j = middle; k = 0;
while (i!=n1 || j!=n2) { ...
```

should be changed to this

```
i = 0; j = 0; k = p;
while (i!=n1 && j!=n2) {...
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a stupid mistake.I guess that is what was causing the fault. The error doesn't occur anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Change this code:

```
if (buffer1[i] <= buffer2[j]) A[k++] = buffer1[i++];
else A[k++] = buffer2[j++];
```

to this:

```
if (buffer1[i] <= buffer2[j]) {
    printf("in if : i = %d : k = %d\n", i, k);
    A[k++] = buffer1[i++];
} else {
    A[k++] = buffer2[j++];
}
```

Now run your program. See the indexes you are trying to use to access the arrays when the segmentation fault occurs:

```
in if : i = 516 : k = 528
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Now you see your problem I am sure.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion. That made debugging easier.

Comment: Remember to select an answer as 'The Answer'. I think @rakinhaider gave you the best one.